# Cython: How do I get cython .pyx to recompile

Tags: python, compilation, cython, python-import

Using this method to compile the pyx files:

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
```

The .pyx file is not recompiled and reloaded after doing:

```
pyximport.install()
import module_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was using an IPython console, closing then opening a new console and then importing it again works.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative could be to do the following:

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install(reload_support=True)
import module_name
```

Comment: recompilation will not work without restarting the console, as the .pyd file is locked by the process.

Comment: That is correct. This method only avoids closing and opening the console, but still requires a console restart.